# How to append text to the end of a Text datablock with Python

Tags: python

To add text to a Text datablock, you use the script `text.write("Text")`. This puts the text wherever the cursor is. I want to put the text at the end of the Text datablock (in other words, append). Is there a way to do this with Python?

Comment: Haven't looked too much into this but should be able to use `bpy.ops.text.move(type='FILE_BOTTOM')` to set the cursor position to end of text block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Write nothing first**

Yes it writes at the cursor location, but will notice then seeks to file end. *As mentioned in doc string*

```
>>> t = D.texts['Text']
>>> t.write(
write()
Text.write(text)
write text at the cursor location and advance to the end of the text block
```

Simply write nothing to seek to EOF

```
t.write("")
```

Alternatively can set the cursor, as an example have used ints greater than existing lines and character length to make sure the cursor is at EOF.

```
 t.cursor_set(44444444, character=44444444)
```

in both cases may require writing a new blank line.

```
t.write("\n")
```