# How to use an internal text file in an Add-on

Tags: python, scripting

Can someone show me an example how I can read the content of an internal text file?
Let's say I append a text file from another Blend file with a known internal name ("*Environment*") and some text data in it. I would like to read an process the content from within an Add-on. I know how to read an external file but I would like to keep this text file internal (after the append) so that it gets saved with the blender file.

I can access the internal file with: bpy.data.texts['*Environment*'].
I tried autocomplete after this and there are lot's of possibilities but I can't figure out how to simply read or write the content of this data block. What is the "best practice" to do this? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: This might help you, here's a link to the relevant docs. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Text.html I think you want `for line in text.lines: print(line.body)` or `text.as_string()`

Comment: A couple old links you may find useful for the basic access to text data block contents. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181187/read-the-contents-of-a-text-datablock?rq=1 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178120/how-to-append-text-to-the-end-of-a-text-datablock-with-python?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are a few funtions I had setup in an old script that can provide some insight to reading, writing and working with data from a text datablock.

## Sample writing to a data block:

Pass a mesh object to the function to create a new (or overwrite an existing) text datablock in the current blender session based on the name of the object.

```py
def mesh_to_txt(obj):
    txtname = obj.name
    verts = [v.co for v in obj.data.vertices]
    edges = [e for e in obj.data.edges]
    faces = [f for f in obj.data.polygons]
    if txtname not in bpy.data.texts:
        ntxt = bpy.data.texts.new(txtname)
    else:
        ntxt = bpy.data.texts[txtname]
        ntxt.clear()
    # verts
    ntxt.write(f"verts = [\n")
    for v in verts:
        ntxt.write(f"\t{v.to_tuple()},\n")
    ntxt.write(f"\t]\n")
    # edges
    ntxt.write(f"edges = [\n")
    for e in edges:
        ntxt.write(f"\t[")
        for v in e.vertices:
            ntxt.write(f"{v},")
        ntxt.write(f"],\n")
    ntxt.write(f"\t]\n")
    # faces
    ntxt.write(f"faces = [\n")
    for f in faces:
        ntxt.write(f"\t[")
        for v in f.vertices:
            ntxt.write(f"{v},")
        ntxt.write(f"],\n")
    ntxt.write(f"\t]\n")
```

A new text block will be created based on the name of the selected object and data formated like so:

```py
verts = [
    (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    (1.0, 1.0, -1.0),
    (1.0, -1.0, 1.0),
    (1.0, -1.0, -1.0),
    (-1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    (-1.0, 1.0, -1.0),
    (-1.0, -1.0, 1.0),
    (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0),
    ]
edges = [
    [5,7,],
    [1,5,],
    [0,1,],
    [7,6,],
    [2,3,],
    [4,5,],
    [2,6,],
    [0,2,],
    [7,3,],
    [6,4,],
    [4,0,],
    [3,1,],
    ]
faces = [
    [0,4,6,2,],
    [3,2,6,7,],
    [7,6,4,5,],
    [5,1,3,7,],
    [1,0,2,3,],
    [5,4,0,1,],
    ]
```

## Reading data from a text datablock

Function that when given a string name corresponding to a text datablock reads the above format creating lists to use elsewhere. If the name provided `txtname` is not found in the currect blend session the return values are empty lists.

```py
def txt_to_mesh(txtname):
    verts = []
    edges = []
    faces = []
    line = 0
    if txtname in bpy.data.texts:
        ntxt = bpy.data.texts[txtname]
    else:
        return verts, edges, faces
    ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
    rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
    
    if rd_line.startswith('verts'):
        line += 1
        ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
        rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
        while rd_line.startswith('\t('):
            verts.append(mathutils.Vector(eval(rd_line[1:-1])))
            line += 1
            ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
            rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
        # skip to edges or faces
        while rd_line.startswith('\t'):
            line += 1
            ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
            rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
        
    if rd_line.startswith('edges'):
        line += 1
        ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
        rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
        while rd_line.startswith('\t['):
            edges.append(eval(rd_line[1:-1]))
            line += 1
            ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
            rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
        # skip to edges or faces
        while rd_line.startswith('\t'):
            line += 1
            ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
            rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
            
    if rd_line.startswith('faces'):
        line += 1
        ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
        rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
        while rd_line.startswith('\t['):
            faces.append(eval(rd_line[1:-1]))
            line += 1
            ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
            rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
        # skip to edges or faces
        while rd_line.startswith('\t'):
            line += 1
            ntxt.cursor_set(line, character=0, select=False)
            rd_line = ntxt.current_line.body
    return verts, edges, faces
```

## Using information read from datablock:

Function to create a mesh object from verts, edges, faces.

```py
def add_mesh(name, verts, faces, edges=None, col_name=""):    
    if edges is None:
        edges = []
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(mesh.name, mesh)
    if bpy.data.collections.get(col_name):
        col = bpy.data.collections.get(col_name)
    else:
        col = bpy.context.scene.collection
    col.objects.link(obj)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
```